# CWnd::CreateEx() fails after replacing WS_CHILD with WS_POPUP

Tags: mfc

When user click a button, I would like to bring up another window. So in the OnBnClicked..() function, I added following code:

```
CWnd* window = new CWnd;
BOOL result = window->CreateEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("STATIC"), _T("Hi"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 20, 20, m_hWnd, (HMENU)1234);
window->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

This works, except it created a child window. What I need is a separate window. So I modified the code by changing "WS_CHILD" to "WS_POPUP", and "m_hWnd" to "NULL".

```
CWnd* window = new CWnd;
BOOL result = window->CreateEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("STATIC"), _T("Hi"), WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 20, 20, NULL, (HMENU)1234);
window->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

But now, the CreateEx() call returns FALSE. I would appreciate some pointer.

**[Edit:]**

I updated the code as following. But still seeing the same issue. Also, even when CreateEx() returns FALSE, GetLastError() actually returns 0.

```
CWnd* window = new CalibrationWindow;
LPCTSTR className = NULL;
if (!className) {
className = AfxRegisterWndClass(
    CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW,
  ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW),
  (HBRUSH) ::GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH),
  ::LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION));
}
BOOL isValid = ::IsWindow(GetSafeHwnd());
BOOL result = window->CreateEx(0, _T(className), _T("Hi"), WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 20, 20, m_hWnd, (HMENU)1234);
DWORD errorCode;
if (!result) {
    errorCode = GetLastError();
}
window->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: If CreateEx returns FALSE then call GetLastError() for more information about why it failed.

Comment: There is no point in creating a window with CWnd. You can't do anything in the window because you can't receive messages sent to that window. Use a class you derive from CWnd instead, so you can add message handlers.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP, I agree with your comment on using CWnd. But that shouldn't affect the windows creation behavior, right?

Comment: Your second parameter to `CreateEx` is wrong. `className` is of type `LPCTSTR` already, remove the `_T ` macro. This will not compile when you enable UNICODE. Also, when you're not creating a `WS_CHILD`-window the `HMENU` parameter really is a handle to a menu. Either pass a valid `HEMNU` or `NULL`.

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you for pointing out the HMENU issue. Setting it to NULL solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nID` or `nIDorHMenu` parameter for [`CWnd::CreateEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atzdh4ys.aspx) is an 'overloaded' parameter that either specifies a control ID or a menu ID.

For a child window ([`WS_CHILD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx#ws_child) window styles) it is the control identifier. You can specify any value as long as it is unique among all child windows with the same parent window.

For a popup window on the other hand (a window that does have `WS_CHILD` window style) it is the menu identifier. In this case it has to be a valid [`HMENU`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646977.aspx). Passing a made up value will cause window creation to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to create a window out of your CWnd-derived class using a different method:

```
CWndDerived myWnd;

LPCTSTR className = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW,
    nullptr,
    (HBRUSH) ::GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH),
    nullptr);
myWnd.CreateEx(
    0,  // WS_EX_TOPMOST
    className,
    _T("Title"),
    WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
    0, 0, 300, 200,
    m_hWnd,
    nullptr,
    nullptr);
```

This allows you to have your `CWndDerived myWnd` as a member variable (should you need it) of your other window and retain all the goodies that come with MSVC's MFC class editor.

I hope this helps